# GridSearch for best model: Save and load parameters

Tags: python, parameters, scikit-learn, pickle, grid-search

I like to run following workflow:

1. Selecting a model for text vectorization
2. Defining a list of parameters
3. Applying a pipeline with GridSearchCV on the parameters, using LogisticRegression() as a baseline to find the best model parameters
4. Save the best model (parameters)
5. Load the best model paramerts so that we can apply a range of other classifiers on this defined model.

Here is code that you can reproduce:

**GridSearch:**

```
%%time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
np.random.seed(0)

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/dqKFZ12m')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split([simple_preprocess(doc) for doc in data.text],
                                                    data.label, random_state=0)

# Find best Tfidf model using LR
pipeline = Pipeline([
  ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=' '.join, tokenizer=None)),
  ('clf', LogisticRegression())
  ])

parameters = {
              'tfidf__max_df': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
              'tfidf__smooth_idf': (True, False),
              'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2', None),
              }

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=2, verbose=1)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(grid.best_params_)

# Save model
#joblib.dump(grid.best_estimator_, 'best_tfidf.pkl', compress = 1) # this unfortunately includes the LogReg
joblib.dump(grid.best_params_, 'best_tfidf.pkl', compress = 1) # Only best parameters
```

> Fitting 2 folds for each of 24 candidates, totalling 48 fits
>       {'tfidf__smooth_idf': True, 'tfidf__norm': 'l2', 'tfidf__max_df': 0.25}

**Load Model with best parameters:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Load best parameters
tfidf_params = joblib.load('best_tfidf.pkl')

pipeline = Pipeline([
  ('vec', TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=' '.join, tokenizer=None).set_params(**tfidf_params)), # here is the issue?
  ('clf', LogisticRegression())
  ])

cval = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
print("Cross-Validation Score: %s" % (np.mean(cval)))
```

> ValueError: Invalid parameter tfidf for estimator
>   TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', binary=False, decode_error='strict',
>           dtype=, encoding='utf-8', input='content',
>           lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=1,
>           ngram_range=(1, 1), norm='l2',
>           preprocessor=,
>           smooth_idf=True, stop_words=None, strip_accents=None,
>           sublinear_tf=False, token_pattern='(?u)\b\w\w+\b',
>           tokenizer=None, use_idf=True, vocabulary=None). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

**Question:**

**How can I load the best parameters of the Tfidf model?**

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
joblib.dump(grid.best_params_, 'best_tfidf.pkl', compress = 1) # Only best parameters
```

saves the parameters of the `pipeline`, not the TfidfVectorizer. So do this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
  # Change the name to be same as before
  ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=' '.join, tokenizer=None)),
  ('clf', LogisticRegression())
  ])

pipeline.set_params(**tfidf_params)
```

Comment: Returns the same error: `ValueError: Invalid parameter tfidf for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,...`

Comment: @Christopher Ah yes. I have updated the answer. You need to use the same names for the pipeline components as you used before. Change `vec` to `tfidf`